# Matrix to vector conversions, In scheme, I'm trying to convert a matrix to a vector, in this example the output should be '(4 6 8)

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (matrix-to-vector op mat)
  (foldl op (car mat) (lambda(x) (map (op (car x)) (cdr mat)))
))

(matrix-to-vector + '((1 2 3) (3 4 5)))
```

Output should be '(4 6 8),
I keep getting error

```
. . foldl: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: #<procedure:....rkt:90:22>
  argument position: 3rd
  other arguments...:
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't apply `+` to one argument at a time – `(+ 3)` is 3, not a procedure that adds 3 to an argument.

Comment: Please add a new question if you want to drastically change the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the parameters of `foldl` in the correct order (i.e., first *proc*, then *init*, and finally *list*). Moreover, the lambda function must have two parameters (since `op` is a binary operator).

```
(define (matrix-to-vector op mat)
  (foldl (lambda(x y) (map op x y)) (car mat) (cdr mat)))
```

Examples:

```
> (matrix-to-vector + '((1 2 3) (3 4 5)))
'(4 6 8)

> (matrix-to-vector + '((1 2 3) (3 4 5) (1 1 1)))
'(5 7 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% mit-scheme
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux

1 ]=> (apply map + '((1 2 3) (3 4 5)) )

;Value: (4 6 8)

1 ]=>
```